# C# Win32 Interop Crashes when Enumerating Window Handles

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, interop, pinvoke

I have a C# wrapper for some Win32 operations involving window handles, but I am experiencing an unexpected crash, with no details, when I call a Win32 function.

Interestingly, this whole code sample works fine when the class is constructed (at application init time), but later fails when the same `buildCache()` method is called.

Here is the relevant code:

```
public delegate bool CallBack(int hWnd, int lParam);

public class Win32Interop {
    private Dictionary<int, string> windowCache = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    public Win32Interop() {
        buildCache();
    }

    public void buildCache() {
        windowCache.Clear();

        CallBack hWndCacher = new CallBack(saveHWndHandler);
        EnumWindows(hWndCacher, 0);
    }

    public void doThings(string title, uint message, bool rebuildCache = false) {
    //Use the window title to get its handle
        int hWnd = titleToHWnd(title, rebuildCache);
        SendMessage(hWnd, message, 0, 0);
    }

    private bool saveHWndHandler(int hWnd, int lParam) {
        if(IsWindow(hWnd) != 0) {       / ***** CRASHES HERE ***** /
            int length = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
            StringBuilder title = new StringBuilder(length + 1);

            GetWindowText(hWnd, title, title.Capacity);
            string formatted = title.ToString().Trim();

            windowCache.Add(hWnd, formatted);
        }

        return true;
    }

    private int titleToHWnd(string title, bool rebuildCache = false) {
        if(rebuildCache)
            buildCache();

        if(windowCache.ContainsValue(title)) {
            return windowCache.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Contains(title)).Key;
        } else {
            throw new KeyNotFoundException(string.Format("\"{0}\" is not a window title which is available in the cache.", title));
        }
    }

    #region Win32 API Functions
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int EnumWindows(CallBack lpEnumFunc, int lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetWindowText(int hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int maxCount);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetWindowTextLength(int hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int IsWindow(int hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.lib")]
    private static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    #endregion
}
```

Inside of the `saveHWndHandler()` method, I've marked the line were the debugger shows execution stops. Interestingly, there are usually ~300 window handles returned by `EnumWindows()`, and it always crashes on iteration number 45 or 46. The window handle it crashes on is a reasonable value, such as 12345.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `IsWindow()` should return `0`, if a window was not associated with the handle, not crash the thread.

Does anyone know why this is happening? There isn't a thrown exception, or any details in the Windows event log.

Thank you.

> For those who don't want to figure out the buildCache() process works:
>  (1.) When `buildCache()` is called, the dictionary of `<HWnd, Title>` values is cleared.
>  (2.) The Win32 function `EnumWindows()` is called, which calls the `saveHWndHandler()` method for each window handle.
>  (3.) `saveHWndHandler()` will check if the current window handle still exists, the call another Win32 to function to get the window title from the handle.
>  (4.) The title and window handle are added to the dictionary.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Perhaps, but the handler stops in the middle of its execution at the first Win32 API call around the 45-46th iteration. That seems too consistent to be an act of the GC.

Comment: @AdamMaras You where right, I removed my incorrect comments.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain no worries, friend.

Comment: Is your process 32 bit or 64 bit?

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce your issue, but a likely problem is that **all** of your P/Invoke signatures are wrong. `HWND`, `LPARAM`, and `WPARAM` data types need to at least be mapped to `IntPtr` in P/Invoke code.

```
private delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString,
    int nMaxCount);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool IsWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam,
    IntPtr lParam);
```

You'll need to change your corresponding instance method signatures and usages to match these correct signatures.

Comment: Looking into that now... What about return types? In your code you have both `int` and `IntPtr` return types.

Comment: @spryno724 `GetWindowText` and `GetWindowTextLength` return *actual integer values* (string length) whereas `SendMessage` returns an `LRESULT` which could be anything (an integer value, a pointer, an error code). When in doubt, check the MSDN documentation as to what the Win32 function returns.